# c# csharp / php / mysql connection

Tags: c#, php

In c#:

```
private void send_password_chk(){
    string response = Sendpw ("http://localhost/quiz/passwordchk.php?idid="+Gameid+"&pass="+Gamepw);
}

private string Sendpw(string url)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
    catch(WebException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I click the button , the function executes.

After I clicked button, in PHP:

```
$id_val = $_GET["idid"];
$pw_val = $_GET["pass"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO member (gameid, gamepw, nickname, birth, gender) VALUES ('".$id_val."',password('".$pw_val."'),'");
```

I execute the PHP code and I get this result:

> Notice: Undefined index: idid in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/quiz/passwordchk.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/quiz/passwordchk.php on line 9

But the insert query is OK. The database has the data.

What is the problem?

Comment: **SQL Injection Alert**. Do not use string concatenation when building SQL queries.

Comment: Well the obvious answer is somehow you're not getting idid+pass sent to your php code... as it clearly says $_GET["idid"] doesnt exist.